# How to get real-time update of model in Agility.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is in Agility.js there's a event call 'change'. This even will be call every time any model of the object change. My problem is the model will only change on losing focus or pressing enter, but I want it to update every time someone type something on it. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you need to bind the event handler to the "keypress"

Comment: This was my idea, but I have no idea on how to force to update of the model in Agility.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this forcing the event 'change' on the event 'keyup'.

```
'keyup input' : function(obj){
    this.view.$('input').change();
    console.log(this.model.get()); 
}
```

Here a snippet showing in action:

http://jsbin.com/ibayeb/4/edit